# MATLAB: How to access 'Duration' datatype

Tags: matlab

Consider the following example

```
xDATA = data_timestamp;
[~,~,Days,Hour,Min,~] = datevec(xDATA(2:end) - xDATA(1:end - 1));
BadSamplingTime = find((Days)> 0 | (Hour)> 0 |(Min)> 5 );
```

In which xData contains a vector of time stamps and I am trying to find the samples with sampling time greater than 5 mins in between , the algorithm works fine but it creates 3 extra vectors for the data as big as my timestamp vector(the size to time stamp vector is pretty huge) whereas if I do this

```
DurationTime = xDATA(2:end) - xDATA(1:end - 1);
```

Instead of the second line it will just create one vector of same length of 'duration' data type which will be much easier to handle because but the problem I cant seem to access each index of the duration data type 
for example

```
DurationTime(5,1)

ans = 

   26:00:01
```

I need to access this 26 hours part , does anyone have any idea how to do that ? or a better suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `duration`-object and then use it to compare it with the duration vector `DurationTime`. The result of `a>b` is a logical vector that can be directly used to index the elements of `DurationTime` and thus giving you all the values where the duration is greater than 5 minutes.
Sidenote: You can calculate the difference/duration directly with `diff`.

*Code:*

```
% create example data
xDATA = (([0:4,4+26*60,4+26*60+1:4+26*60+5])/24/60+datetime('now')).';

% calculate the durations
DurationTime = xDATA(2:end) - xDATA(1:end-1);      % as in the question
%DurationTime = diff(xDATA);                       % alternative

% get index and values of all durations greater than 5 minutes
ind = find(DurationTime>duration(0,5,0))
DurationTime(ind)

% get values of all durations greater than 5 minutes (direct solution, if no index needed)
DurationTime(DurationTime>duration(0,5,0));
```

*Result:*

```
ind =

     5

ans = 

   26:00:00
```

Comment: if I need to find the indices of the duration time matrix what should I do ? because find() doesnt work for duration datatype

Comment: @Umar I added it in my answer. You can use `find` on the logical vector because the entries where duration is greater than 5 minutes have value `1` which is non-zero. Thus, `find` returns that index.